# Downcast parameter in Child class Java

Tags: java

```
public class Contract extends StandardEntity {
/***/
@Composition
@OnDeleteInverse(DeletePolicy.UNLINK)
@OnDelete(DeletePolicy.CASCADE)
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "contract")
protected List<Objective> objectives;
/***/
```

Is it possible to downgrade argument *objectives* in child class (ContractWthDeadLines extends Contract) from List< Objective> to List< ObjectiveWitchDeadLine>:

```
public class ObjectiveWitchDeadLine extends Objective
```

Comment: Also, on an unrelated note, I assume that's supposed to be `WithDeadline`, not `WitchDeadline`.  The latter to me implies potions and brooms and warts and things.

Comment: No. You can not **downgrade** from List< Objective> to List< ObjectiveWitchDeadLine> or **upgrade** from  List< ObjectiveWitchDeadLine> to List< Objective>. This can not compile.

Comment: Thanks for answers. Unfortunately, generic SuperClass is not a solution and it is seems no way to do it without it.
So i will figure out another way to solve that task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your Contract class generic

```
public class Contract<T extends Objective> extends StandardEntity {
   protected List<T> objectives;
}
```

and if you extend it you can change the type

```
public class ContractDeadline extends Contract<ObjectiveWitchDeadLine> {
}
```

Comment: No way i can do it without generic parent class?

Comment: not in a type safe way